# AsyncCallback tied to a WebRequest is never reached

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, .net-3.5

I have an ASPX page which should retrieve some content (some plain text data) asynchronously, and write something before/during/after the operation.

Currently, I can reach the "during" step but page content doesn't change anymore afterwards.

Big issue is I **cannot** perform **any** kind of debugging due to infrastructure (mis)configuration and not being allowed to run Remote Debugging Tools, I have to rely on publishing and see what happens...

Code behind looks like this (This is a .NET 3.5 (changing target framework is *not* an option) project created under VS2008 and later upgraded to VS2010)

```
void Page_Load()
{
    myLabel = "Preparing to fetch content ...";
    FetchContent();
}

void FetchContent()
{
    try {
        // "http://myUrl" returns text with header 'Content-disposition: inline;'
        // If called directly, Text can be seen in the browser alright.
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://myUrl");
        myLabel = "Fetching ...";
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback((result)=>
        {
            //EXCEPTION HERE: 401 Unauthorized ??? url works via browser!
            WebResponse resp = request.EndGetResponse(result);

            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            myLabel = "Done";
        }        
    } catch {myLabel = "Request KO"; }
}
```

In the ASPX code, `myLabel` is simply shown:

```
<body>
    <pre><%=myLabel %></pre>
</body>
```

The url responds fairly quickly if called from a browser, but in this code `myLabel` never shows `Done.`, it stays on the `Fetching...` text like the callback is never fired.

Am I missing something obvious here ?

**UPDATE**

Closer inspection revealed that `EndGetResponse` returns a `401 Unauthorized` status code. It works flawlessly if I invoke the exact same url via a browser though ! Some now more focused searching got me the solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding out the `401 Unauthorized` status code in the response, I managed to find other answers right here on SO which made me solve my (as it turns out) trivial issue adding this:

```
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```